# Short streams and tiny basins | QGIS-SAGA

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology, basin, strahler

After watching a lot of tutorials and trying all approaches I still somehow manage to get streams that are too short over my DEM, resulting in very small basins. I do it the standard way:

- Get a DEM
- Fill sinks with the Wang & Liu algorithm in SAGA
- Get the Strahler Orders

The resulting streams are very short, resulting in countless small basins. I figured that using r.watershed I can get a better model, but then the stream segments only appear by the outlets.

I want to be able to get the basins that correspond to a specific order. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or is my topography just special?

[image]